# Scrapy and Selenium : only scrape two pages

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, scrapy

I want to crawl a website,  there are more than 10 pages
every page has 10 links, the spider will get the links`def parse():`
and go the the link to crawl another data I want `def parse_detail():`

Please guide me how to write to crawl only two pages not all pages THX
Here is my code it only crawl one pages and than the spider closed

```
def __init__(self):
    self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    dispatcher.connect(self.spider_closed, signals.spider_closed)

def parse(self, response):
    self.driver.implicitly_wait(20) 
    self.driver.get(response.url)
    sites = self.driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("")
    for site in sites:
        item = CItem()
        linkiwant = site.find_element_by_css_selector(" ") 
        start = site.find_element_by_css_selector(" ")  
        item['link'] = linkiwant.get_attribute("href") 
        item['start_date']  = start.text
        yield Request(url=item['link'], meta={'item':item}, callback=self.parse_detail)  

    #how to write to only catch 2 pages??
    i=0
    if i< 2:
        try:
            next = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("/li[@class='p_next'][1]")   
            next_page = next.text
            if next_page == "next_page":  
                next.click()    
                self.driver.refresh()  
                yield Request(self.driver.current_url, callback=self.parse)
                i+=1
        except:
             print "page not found"     
def parse_detail(self,response):
    item = response.meta['item']
    self.driver.implicitly_wait(20)  
    self.driver.get(response.url)
    sel = Selector(response)
    sites = sel.css("")            
    for site in sites:
        item['title'] = site.css(" ").extract()[0] 
        item['titleURL'] = site.css(" ").extract()[0]
        ..
        yield item   
def spider_closed(self, spider):
    self.driver.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make `i` persistent:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.page_num = 0
    self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    dispatcher.connect(self.spider_closed, signals.spider_closed)
```

```
    #how to write to only catch 2 pages??
    if self.page_num < 2:
        try:
            next = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("/li[@class='p_next'][1]")   
            next_page = next.text
            if next_page == "next_page":  
                next.click()    
                self.driver.refresh()  
                yield Request(self.driver.current_url, callback=self.parse)
                self.page_num += 1
        except:
             print "page not found"
```

Comment: I have a question.if there are 10 pages in a website,but I set self.page_num < 12, will if codition except when it got 10 pages or the if will run twelve times?

Comment: **Try it!!** I'm guessing that it will probably stop, but don't take my word for it. You could add `else: print 'no next page'` right after `if next_page == "next_page":` to see whether that ends the function.