# How to extract data from dynamic websites like Flipkart using selenium and Scrapy?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, scrapy

As [Flipkart.com](http://www.flipkart.com) shows only 15 to 20 results on 1st page and when scrolled it shows more results. Scrapy extracts results of 1st page successfully but not of next pages. I tried using Selenium for it, but couldn't find success.
Here is my code :-

```
from scrapy.spider import Spider

from scrapy.selector import Selector

from flipkart.items import FlipkartItem

from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider

from selenium import webdriver

class FlipkartSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "flip1"
    allowed_domains = ["flipkart.com"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.flipkart.com/beauty-and-personal-care/personal-care-appliances/hair-dryers/pr?sid=t06,79s,mh8&otracker=nmenu_sub_electronics_0_Hair%20Dryers"
]

    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()

    def parse(self, response):
        sel = Selector(response)
        self.driver.get(response.url)
        while True:
            next = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@id="show-more-results"]')
            try:

                sites = sel.select('//div[@class="gd-col gu12 browse-product fk-inf-scroll-item"] | //div[@class="pu-details lastUnit"]')
                for site in sites:
                    item = FlipkartItem()
                    item['title'] = site.select('div//a[@class="lu-title"]/text() | div[1]/a/text()').extract()
                    item['price'] = site.select('div//div[@class="pu-price"]/div/text() | div//div[@class="pu-final"]/span/text()').extract()
                    yield item
                next.wait_for_page_to_load("30")
            except:
                break
            self.driver.close()
```

,My items.py is:-

```
import scrapy
class FlipkartItem(scrapy.Item):
    title=scrapy.Field()
    price=scrapy.Field()
```

and Following output I get is only for 15 items:-

```
[{"price": ["Rs. 599"], "title": ["\n Citron Elegant 1400 W HD001 Hair Dryer (Pink)\n "]},

{"price": ["Rs. 799"], "title": ["\n Citron Vogue 1800 W HD002 Hair Dryer (White)\n "]},

{"price": ["Rs. 645"], "title": ["\n Philips HP8100/00 Hair Dryer (Blue)\n "]},

{"price": ["Rs. 944"], "title": ["\n Philips HP8111/00 Hair Dryer\n "]},

{"price": ["Rs. 171"], "title": ["\n Nova Professional With 2 Speed NV-1290 Hair Dryer (Pink...\n "]},

{"price": ["Rs. 175"], "title": ["\n Nova NHD 2840 Hair Dryer\n "]},

{"price": ["Rs. 775"], "title": ["\n Philips HP 8112 Hair Dryer\n "]},

{"price": ["Rs. 1,925"], "title": ["\n Philips HP8643/00 Miss Fresher's Pack Hair Straightener...\n "]},

{"price": ["Rs. 144"], "title": ["\n Nova Foldable N-658 Hair Dryer (White, Pink)\n "]},

{"price": ["Rs. 1,055"], "title": ["\n Philips HP8100/46 Hair Dryer\n "]},

{"price": ["Rs. 849"], "title": ["\n Panasonic EH-ND12-P62B Hair Dryer (Pink)\n "]},

{"price": ["Rs. 760"], "title": ["\n Panasonic EH-ND11 Hair Dryer (White)\n "]},

{"price": ["Rs. 1,049"], "title": ["\n Panasonic EH-ND13-V Hair Dryer (Violet)\n "]},

{"price": ["Rs. 1,554"], "title": ["\n Philips 1600 W HP4940 Hair Dryer (White & Light Pink)\n "]},

{"price": ["Rs. 2,008"], "title": ["\n Philips Kerashine HP8216/00 Hair Dryer\n "]}]
```

Comment: Perhaps you could first ask them if they'll share their data with you?  If they like you they'll probably give you a better way to access the data, and if they don't you're probably going to have a war whereby they keep blocking your spider and you have to keep working on ways around it.

Comment: @John, They have already shared their data via website. I am just making a script using python,scrappy and selenium to automatically retrieve their data from html pages to a txt or .json file.

Comment: i m working on same project....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **I managed it differently..  See my code for further reference.  Working fine for complete site..**

```
class FlipkartSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "flip1"
    allowed_domains = ["flipkart.com"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.flipkart.com/tablets/pr?sid=tyy%2Chry&q=mobile&ref=b8b64676-065a-445c-a6a1-bc964d5ff938"
    ]
    '''def is_element_present(self, finder, selector, wait_time=None):
        wait_time = wait_time or self.wait_time
        end_time = time.time() + wait_time
        while time.time() < end_time:
            if finder(selector):
                return True
        return False
        def is_element_present_by_xpath(self, xpath, wait_time=None):
        return self.is_element_present(self.find_by_xpath, xpath, wait_time)
        '''
    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()


    def parse(self, response):
        sel = Selector(response) 
        self.driver.get(response.url)
        block="block"
        hyper="http://www.flipkart.com"
        print hyper
        #i=0
        while True:
            self.driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(10000000,10000000)")
            self.driver.set_page_load_timeout(10000)
            try:
                show = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@id="show-more-results"]').value_of_css_property('display')
                if show==block:
                    self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@id="show-more-results"]').click()
                no_more = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="no-more-results" and @class="dont-show"]').value_of_css_property('display')
                if no_more==block:
                    break;
                time.sleep(5)
                self.driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(10000000,10000000)")

                self.driver.set_page_load_timeout(10000)
                #if i==7:
                #   break
            except NoSuchElementException:
                print "pungi"
                break
        #down = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@id="show-more-results"]')
        #location = down.location
        #self.((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.scrollBy(10000,10000);");
        #next = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@id="show-more-results"]')
        response = TextResponse(url=response.url, body=self.driver.page_source, encoding='utf-8')
        try:
            #self.driver.set_page_load_timeout(10000)
            #driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, location.get('y')")
            sites = response.xpath('//div[@class="gd-col gu12 browse-product fk-inf-scroll-item"] | //div[@class="pu-details lastUnit"] |  //div[@class="pu-visual-section"]')
            for site in sites:
                item = FlipkartItem()
                item['title'] = site.xpath('div//a[@class="lu-title"]/text() | div[1]/a/text()').extract()
                item['price'] = site.xpath('div//div[@class="pu-price"]/div/text() | div//div[@class="pu-final"]/span/text()').extract()
                item['rating'] = site.xpath('div[@class="pu-rating"]/div/@title').extract()
                item['image'] = site.xpath('a/img/@src').extract()
                data = site.xpath('a/@href').extract()
                print data
                item['link'] = data

                #print rating
                yield item
            '''for site in sites:
                item = FlipkartItem()
                item['title'] = site.xpath('div//a[@class="lu-title"]/text() | div[1]/a/text()').extract()
                item['price'] = site.xpath('div//div[@class="pu-price"]/div/text() | div//div[@class="pu-final"]/span/text()').extract()
                item['rating'] = site.xpath('div[@class="pu-rating"]/div/@title').extract()
                #print rating
                yield item'''
            #next.click()
            #self.driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(10000000,10000000)")
        except:
            #break
            a=10
        self.driver.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to force the webdriver loading of more results.
In order to be able to interact with the other results, the webdriver need to scroll the page until the elements appear.

The code for scrolling is:

```
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, location.get('y')")
```

To decide where to scroll you can find an element in the lower part of the page (as example the footer) and keep scrolling to it.To get the coordinates of the element you can use the Webelement property location

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
down = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//someXpath")
location = down.location
```

Comment: @Mercury I noticed a downgrade. something not working in the proposed solution already accepted ?

Comment: @arberna, It is successfully loading other pages products (only in browser)  but scrappy do not crawls it to .json file. Still only 1st page entries are output in file.

Comment: In your question you were pointing out the problem with Selenium to move to the next page. My answer as the other one proposed were solving that issue. For Scrapy once you get to a new page, you have to force scrapy update the current url and parse the new code. An example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25215623/scrapy-and-selenium-only-scrap-two-pages

Comment: Thank you, I got it, that my question was only regarding selenium.

Comment: @Mercury as I suggested check the code in the similar question. The key is   self.driver.refresh() ,  yield Request(self.driver.current_url, callback=self.parse)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Javascript to scroll down the page.

Following code will scroll the page down by 10000,10000 in x & y direction. As 10000 is big number so it takes you to the bottom of page. Once you are at bottom , AJAX request is fired by flipkart to load more item.

```
window.scrollBy(10000,10000);
```

I am not sure how we can do that in scrapy but using selenium it is easy.

Here is code

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.scrollBy(10000,10000);");
```