# use scrapy to crawl node

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm trying to use scrapy to crawl some advertise information from [this](http://www.lazada.vn/dien-thoai-may-tinh-bang/?ref=MT) web sites. 
That website has some `div` tag with `class="product-card new_ outofstock installments_ "`.

When I use:

```
items = response.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'product-')]")
```

I get some node with class attribute = `"product-description"` but not `"product-card"`.

When I use:

```
items = response.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'product-card')]")
```

I still get nothing in result.

Why is that ?

Answer (score 0):

The data you want is being populated by javascripts.

You would have to use a `selenium webdriver` to extract the data.

If you want to check before hand if data is being populated using javascript, open a scrapy shell and try extracting the data as below.

```
scrapy shell 'http://www.lazada.vn/dien-thoai-may-tinh-bang/?ref=MT'

>>>response.xpath('//div[contains(@class,"product-card")]')
```

Output:

```
[]
```

Now, if you use the same Xpath in the browser and get a result as below:
[image]

Then the data is populated using scripts and selenium would have to be used to get data.

Here is an example to extract data using selenium:

```
import scrapy
from selenium import webdriver
from scrapy.http import TextResponse

class ProductSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "product_spider"
    allowed_domains = ['lazada.vn']
    start_urls = ['http://www.lazada.vn/dien-thoai-may-tinh-bang/?ref=MT']

    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()

    def parse(self, response):
        self.driver.get(response.url)
        page = TextResponse(response.url, body=self.driver.page_source, encoding='utf-8')
        required_data = page.xpath('//div[contains(@class,"product-card")]').extract()

        self.driver.close()
```

Here are some examples of "selenium spiders":

1. [Executing Javascript Submit form functions using scrapy in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10648644/executing-javascript-submit-form-functions-using-scrapy-in-python)
2. [Snipplr](http://snipplr.com/view/66998/)
3. [Scrapy with selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31183381/scraper-implemented-with-python-using-scrapy-and-selenium-launches-but-shuts-do)
4. [Extract data from dynamic webpages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28122882/how-to-extract-data-from-dynamic-websites-like-flipkart-using-selenium-and-scrap)

Comment: Thanks but i get eror: NameError: global name 'TextResponse' is not defined

Answer (score 0):

As pointed in the previous answer, the content you are trying to scrape is generated dynamically using javascript. If performance is not a big deal for you, then you can use Selenium to emulate a real user and interact with the site. At the same time you can let Scrapy get the data for you.

If you want a similar example of how to do this, consider this tutorial: http://www.6020peaks.com/2014/12/how-to-scrape-hidden-web-data-with-python/